# I deleted my windows google auth (TOTP), how can I log in on BTER without it?

Tags: peercoin, bter

To make a short story:

I have created an account on bter.com along with TOTP (windows, not phone), then I opened the `Google Authenticator for windows`, I put the numbers (XXXXXX). I don't remember exactly what it was. Than I transferred my PPC from BTC-e to Bter (about 200ish PPC). I believe it worked but soon after I was automatically logged out, I tried to log back in, but they asked for TOTP? I went to my google authenticator and put the numbers but didn't work. I believe I did something wrong, after that I delete my account from authenticator and made a new one because maybe something was bugged but could not remember the secret key (20 something letter and number). I need to be connected to my btcer account to see that but I cannot at the moment.

I'm french Canadian so sorry about my writing.

p.s: All I have right now is my PPC address on bter because when I open my btc-e wallet I can see that the transaction has been done. So to make a short story I can't log in to bter.com and my PPC are stuck there...

support@bter.com and admin@bter.com did not answer any of my email (it's been 3 days).

Edit: I know my bter username, password, and fund password.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).